# Parsing file into helm template

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm, helm3

I try parsing file

```
VAR1=https://com.dom
VAR2=abcd=efg=
```

by  template

```
{{- range $path, $_ :=  $.Files.Glob $envPath }}
    {{- range split "\n" ($.Files.Get $path) }}
      {{- if . }}
        {{- $kv := splitList "=" . -}}
          {{- $k := first $kv}}
          {{- if contains "RAW_" $k }}
            {{- first $kv | replace "RAW_" "" | nindent 2}}: {{last $kv | quote }}
            {{ else}}
            {{- first $kv | nindent 2}}: {{last $kv | replace "'" "" | b64enc | quote }}
          {{-  end }}
  {{-  end }}
    {{- end }}
{{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

and got

```
data:
  VAR1: "aHR0cHM6Ly9jb20uZG9t"
  VAR2: ""
```

becouse splitList get last "=", but I want that splitList take only first "=" will take as seporator.
note: base64 have "=" at your hashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tree

```bash
.
├── Chart.yaml
├── charts
├── prop
│   └── varFile
├── templates
│   ├── NOTES.txt
│   ├── _helpers.tpl
│   ├── configmap.yaml
│   └── deployment.yaml
└── values.yaml
```

prop/varFile

```
VAR1=https://com.dom
VAR2=abcd=efg=

VAR4

VAR5=
```

values.yaml

```
varFile: "prop/varFile"
```

templates/configmap.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
    {{- range .Files.Lines .Values.varFile }}
    {{- $arr := split "=" . }}
    {{- $k := $arr._0 }}
    {{- if ge (len $arr) 2 }}
    {{ $k }}: {{ substr (int (add 1 (len $k))) (len .) . | b64enc | quote }}
    {{- else }}
    {{- if ge (len $k) 1 }}
    {{ $k }}: ""
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
    {{- end }}
```

output:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: test
data: 
  data: |-
    VAR1: "aHR0cHM6Ly9jb20uZG9t"
    VAR2: "YWJjZD1lZmc9"
    VAR4: ""
    VAR5: ""
```

Comment: Thank you for help, but I get error(
```
helm template node --debug
install.go:195: [debug] CHART PATH: /tmp/helm/node
Error: template: node/templates/configmap.yaml:11:17: executing "node/templates/configmap.yaml" at <substr (int (add 1 (len $k))) (len .) .>: error calling substr: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [1:0]
helm.go:84: [debug] template: node/templates/configmap.yaml:11:17: executing "node/templates/configmap.yaml" at <substr (int (add 1 (len $k))) (len .) .>: error calling substr: runtime error: slice bounds out of range [1:0]
```

Comment: because there are some lines in your actual file that don't contain ```=```.
This needs to change the above writing and increase the boundary judgment